# Python: How to save discord.py objects in files

Tags: python, discord.py

I have to store a object as a file. The object looks like this:

```
<Message id=--- channel=<TextChannel id=--- name='tname' position=29 news=False category_id=---> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=--- name='mname' discriminator='---' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=--- name='gname' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=41>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

I put those in a dictionary, tried to dump it with json, json said no. Dumped it with pickle to byte: "cannot pickle 'Context' object. Saved it as a blank string, couldn't convert it back to dict (Tried it with ast.literal_eval and json). No success. I really don't know how to save it.

Comment: Which part(s) do you need to save? You could write a function to extract the necessary elements and serialize them, no?

Comment: that should work, thank you!